# logic for adding users in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an E-Commerce website and store products(id & quantity) in session["cart_array"](From Adam Khoury's Tutorials :P). Now I want that I can insert these product details to table known as costumer_orders. I need some logic that can extract these details from the table products and then insert these in customer_orders table. If there is another best solution then please suggest it.
This is my code

```
<?php
$dynamicDisplay = '';
if (isset($_SESSION["name"]) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    //VARIABLES TO SHOW SELETED ITEMS BY THE USER
    $dynamicDisplay .= '<h1>Thank <?php echo $name;?> for Ordering from Us.</h1>';
    $dynamicDisplay .= 'Your Order Details are: <br/>';
    $dynamicDisplay .= '<ol>';

    //FOREACH LOOP FOR ACCESSING ALL ITEMS FROM THE CART
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        $item_id = $each_item["item_id"];
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $product_name = $row['product_name'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $detail = $row['details'];


        //SOME CODE HERE THAT CAN ALSO INSERT THIS DATA IN customer_orders table 
       // I tried this code but nothing happens

 $insertData = "INSERT INTO customer_orders(name, products, price, date )VALUES ($name, $product_name, $price,now())";
        $dataQuery = mysqli_query($con, $insertData);

        }
        $dynamicDisplay .= '<li>' . $product_name . '</li>';
    }
    $dynamicDisplay .= '</ol>';
    $dynamicDisplay .= 'To';
    $dynamicDisplay .= $_SESSION['address'];

}else {
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: *"known as `costumer_orders`"* and you're using `INSERT INTO cutomer_orders` and then not quoting what looks to me being string values which are not quoted.

Comment: best solution is to STOP assuming that queries never fail. You have no error handling whatsoever, which means you're simply ASSUMING nothing could ever go wrong. Even if your SQL syntax is 100% perfect, there's a near infinite number of ways for it to STILL fail. There's exactly ONE way for a query to succeed, but you seem to think that `1:infinity` odds are in your favor... `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($con))` should be the minimum acceptable error checking.

Comment: While testing: Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: sorry! Fred 
I just type here wrong word not in my code..

Comment: `($name, $product_name` unquoted (string) values; will cause an error. What you posted should work once you've quoted those "more than likely" string values and that you started the session.

Comment: Hey! 
Thanks Fred :P
Silly Mistake by me First time

Comment: You're welcome. So, problem solved I take it

Comment: Yup! my problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in comments, string values require them to be quoted.

Your `VALUES ($name, $product_name, $price,now())";` will fail you here and needs to reads as:

```
VALUES ('$name', '$product_name', $price,now())";
```

However, if there happens to be any characters that MySQL will complain about, such as apostrophes, then that too will throw a syntax error.

Therefore, you will need to escape those values, which is something you should be doing in the first place. A prepared statement will take care of all this and help prevent against an SQL injection

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php (apply this to your query).

Also make sure the session was started.

- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php